# writing test class for trigger failing due to second class

Tags: visualforce

i have a trigger on quote with all events.written two classes for this trigger
1.after quote creation product is automatically creating--first class.
2.before quote creation i need to populate contact details in quote automatically----second class.i have written test class for first class successfully.while writing test class for second class the method is not passing due to after insert operation of first class
this is my code on Quote.

### trigger

```
trigger AutoPopulateContactFieldsInQuote on Quote (before insert,before update,after insert,after update,after undelete) {
    if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate){
        AutoPopulateContactFieldsInQuoteHelper a=new AutoPopulateContactFieldsInQuoteHelper();
        a.PopulateContactFieldsInQuote(trigger.new);
    }
    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate || trigger.isundelete){
        AuotCreateProducFromQuotetHelper au = new AuotCreateProducFromQuotetHelper();
        au.AuotCreateProducFromQuote(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

### class

```
/****
This class is responsible for Auto populate Contact fileds like contactname,
email,phone,fax from opportunity into Quote when opportunity has Contactroles
relatedlist 
***/
public class AutoPopulateContactFieldsInQuoteHelper {

    public void PopulateContactFieldsInQuote(list<Quote> quotelist1){

        List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();
        Map<String, Quote> QuotetoOpportunityIDMap = new Map<String, Quote>();
        for( Quote Qid : quotelist1 )
        {
            QuotetoOpportunityIDMap.put( Qid.OpportunityID, Qid ); 
        } 

        List<OpportunityContactRole> Contactlist = [select OpportunityID, IsPrimary,ContactID,contact.email,contact.phone,contact.fax from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityID in :QuotetoOpportunityIDMap.keySet() and IsPrimary = true];

        for (OpportunityContactRole oppConrole : Contactlist) {                            

            Quote quoteToUpdate = QuotetoOpportunityIDMap.get(oppConrole.OpportunityID);

            quoteToUpdate.ContactId = oppConrole.ContactId;       
            quoteToUpdate.phone = oppConrole.Contact.phone;
            quoteToUpdate.fax = oppConrole.Contact.fax;
            quoteToUpdate.email = oppConrole.Contact.email;
            quoteList.add(quoteToUpdate);       
        }
    }
}
```

### test Class

```
@isTest
public class AutoPopulateContactFieldsInQuoteTest{
    static testmethod void PopulateContactFieldsInQuoteTest(){

        account a=new account();
        a.name='tes';
        insert a;

        contact c=new contact();
        c.lastname='ctes';
        c.accountid=a.id;
        insert c;

        opportunity o = new opportunity();
        o.name = 'Testoppty';
        o.StageName = 'lead';
        o.CloseDate = date.today();
        o.accountid = a.Id;
        o.Billing_Type__c='Aggregate';
        insert o;
     /*   list<quote> lq=new list<quote>();
     quote q=new quote();
     q.name='tesq';
     q.contactid=c.id;
     q.email='g@gg.com';
     q.opportunityId = o.Id;//Link Quote and opportunity record
     lq.add(q); 
     insert lq;

    AutoPopulateContactFieldsInQuoteHelper au=new AutoPopulateContactFieldsInQuoteHelper ();
        au.PopulateContactFieldsInQuote(lq);
    AuotCreateProducFromQuotetHelper aa=new AuotCreateProducFromQuotetHelper();
        aa.AuotCreateProducFromQuote(lq); */

    }
}
```

### class

```
/**
 This class is responsible for Auto creation of product record when creation of Quote 
**/
public class AuotCreateProducFromQuotetHelper {

    static Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> quoteRecordTypeMap = Schema.SObjectType.Quote.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    static Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> prodRecordTypeMap = Schema.SObjectType.Product2.getRecordTypeInfosByName();

    public void AuotCreateProducFromQuote(list<quote> newQuotes){ 

        list<product2> productlist = new list<product2>();

            for(Integer i=0; i<newQuotes.size(); i++)    {  
                product2 prod = new product2();

                    if(quoteRecordTypeMap.get('Single Location Quote').getRecordTypeId() == newQuotes[i].RecordTypeId){ 
                        prod.Name=newQuotes[i].Name;
                        prod.Commit__c=newQuotes[i].Commit__c;
                        prod.Burst_Rate__c=newQuotes[i].Burst_Rate__c;
                        prod.Expiration_date__c=newQuotes[i].ExpirationDate; 
                        prod.Bandwidth_Provider__c=newQuotes[i].Provider__c;
                        prod.Terms_of_Service__c=newQuotes[i].Contract_Term_in_Years__c;
                        prod.Margin__c=newQuotes[i].Margin__c;
                        prod.RecordTypeID = prodRecordTypeMap.get('Single Location Product').getRecordTypeId();
                        prod.IsActive=true;
                        productlist.add(prod);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(quoteRecordTypeMap.get('Multiple Locations Quote').getRecordTypeId() == newQuotes[i].RecordTypeId)
                        prod.Name=newQuotes[i].Name;
                        prod.Commit__c=newQuotes[i].Commit__c;
                        prod.Burst_Rate__c=newQuotes[i].Burst_Rate__c;
                        prod.Expiration_date__c=newQuotes[i].ExpirationDate; 
                        prod.Bandwidth_Provider__c=newQuotes[i].Provider__c;

                        productlist.add(prod);   
                    }
            }
        insert productlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gopinath! Could you please [edit] your question to include the specific error message(s) you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you test this class based on the trigger executing by inserting a `quote` since that's what actually calls this class and you need coverage for both. Creating your data and inserting the `quote` is calling the class via the `trigger`, likely creating a conflict when you call the `class` again in your test method.

I also can't help but question the logic of calling your class in both the `beforeInsert` and `afterInsert` trigger contexts as well as the `beforeUpdate` and `afterUpdate` contexts too. Assuming you have some workflow that occurs on Quote, that translates to four times that your class is called every time a quote is created!

At best this should only be a `beforeInsert` and possibly a `beforeUpdate` trigger. The need for the latter is questionable. I would only use it in a `before update` context IF there's been a change in ContactRoles. Otherwise it shouldn't be needed at all. It definitely shouldn't be fired both before and after Insert/Update.